# Validação de input disparando erro 400 com Spring MVC

Tags: java-ee, spring, tomcat

Pessoal, tem um erro chato no qual estou perdendo o sono para descobrir como tratar.

Bem, toda vez na qual vou realizar meu teste verificando a validação de meu campo um erro 400 e disparado.

Não sei mas como faço para poder resolver tal questão. O log do servidor não acusa nada.

abaixo o HTML:

```
<div class="body-nest" id="basic">
    <div class="form_center">


        <c:if test="${validator}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                <span class="entypo-attention"></span> <strong>Opa!</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Você
                não pode deixar o campo abaixo em branco e ele tem que ter mais
                que três caracters!.
            </div>
        </c:if>

        <f:form action="updateCategory" method="get" modelAttribute="categoryModify">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${categoryModify.idCategory}"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <f:input type="text"
                    id="inputCategory" class="form-control" path="ctName" value="${categoryModify.ctName}"/>
            </div>
            <f:button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Alterar</f:button>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="<c:url value="category"/>">Cancelar</a>                            
        </f:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**O controller:**

```
//Mapeamento para mostrar a categoria na tela.
@RequestMapping(value="editCategory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editCategory(Long id, Model model, @Valid Category category, BindingResult result){    
        model.addAttribute("validator", false);
        model.addAttribute("categoryModify", dashboardFacade.getCategoryId(id));
        return "category/updateCategory";    
}

// Update da categoria
@RequestMapping(value="/updateCategory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateCategory( @Valid Category category, @RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam String ctName, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("validator", true);
        return "category/updateCategory";
    } else {
        dashboardFacade.categoryUpdate(ctName, id);
        logger.info("A categoria " + category.getIdCategory() + " pertencente a agência " + dashboardFacade.getAgency() + " foi adicionada.");
        return "redirect:category";
    }
}
```

**Modelo:**

```
@Column(name="ct_name")
@NotEmpty
private String ctName;
```

Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Amigo, esse seu código está meio confuso. Na verdade fazer isso que você está querendo é mais fácil do que você imagina. Dê uma olhada nesses links: [Formulários](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag), 
[Um exemplo prático](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api). Sucesso! :)

Comment: Oi Fábio, na verdade era engano meu mesmo. Legal os links que você mandou. Vai me esclarecer muitas duvidas daqui para frente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso se atentar para a URL para a qual o formulário está redirecionando.

A sua tag `<f:form>` aponta para a URL relativa `updateCategory`, enquanto parece que seu método do controlador aponta para uma URL relativa ao contexto (`/updateCategory`).

Isso se não houver uma anotação na classe (que não aparece no código), que faria a URL do método ser concatenada à URL da classe.

## Exemplo

Supondo que a página com o formulário seja a seguinte:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/category/edit
```

Ao clicar no botão *submit*, relativo, a URL invocada será:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/category/updateCategoy
```

Supondo ainda que o esperado seja:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/updateCategoy
```

Então a solução seria que o atributo `action` do formulário fosse:

```
<f:form action="../updateCategory" ... >
```

Comment: Realmente @utluiz, era realmente esse problema. Na verdade como estou usando o Framework Tiles eu acabe que confundindo um pouco as coisa, mas já consegui entender o funcionamento total!